# How to make nodes the same size without influencing cells in matrix

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-matrix

I'm drawing a tree with tikz and would like the nodes to all have the same size, regardless of content.

This is what my code currently does:

[image: tree: root with 2x1 cells, left child with 3x3 cells, right child with 2x1 cells]

This is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=2cm,
    sibling distance=3cm,
    outer_nodes/.style={shape=rectangle,rounded corners,draw,align=center,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=5cm},
    cells/.style={text height=0.2cm, text width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.2cm, minimum width=0.5}
]
\node[outer_nodes,matrix,matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {
    \node {3};\&\node {6};\\
}
        child {
            node[outer_nodes,matrix,matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {
                \node {$ct_1^5$};\&\node {$ct_2^5$};\&\node {$ct_3^5$};\\
                \node {$cd_1^5$};\&\node {$cd_2^5$};\&\node {$cd_3^5$};\\
                \node {-8}; \& \&\node { 8};\\
            }
        }
        child {
            node[outer_nodes,matrix,matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {
                \node {3};\&\node {3};\\
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried setting the minimum size, but it also affected the cells, making them far to large. Overwriting the cells minimum size by specifying it again didn't work.

I also tried to play around with minimum/text height/size, but I didn't find a combination that worked.

Comment: If you only use the TikZ `matrix` for math matrices it might be better to use `\begin{matrix} ct_1^5 & … \\ …\end{matrix}` and then you could also use `forest` or TikZ's own `\graph` for drawing the diagram which both automate a few things and is less verbose to write down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a two mistakes in your example in this line:

```
cells/.style={text height=0.2cm, text width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.2cm, minimum width=0.5}
```

The key `cells` is already defined as

```
cells/.style={every cell/.append style={#1}}
```

i.e. adding its value to the `every cell` style. By doing `cells/.style` you just defined a style `cells` that is never used by any matrix.

Furthermore,

```
minimum width=0.5
```

contains no node. When PGFmath will evaluate this (during the creation of the matrix node), it will assume `pt` → `0.5pt` which also won't do anything since your matrices are wider than that.

You should do either

```
cells={
    text height=0.2cm, text width=0.5cm, minimum size=1pt}
```

i.e. resetting both `minimum width` and `minimum height` again to the default length (or just `0pt`), or use the `every outer matrix` style which is only applies for the matrix node and not for the nodes in the cells of the matrix:

```
outer_nodes/.style={
    shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center,
    every outer matrix/.append style={
        minimum height=4cm,
        minimum width=5cm
    },
}
```

By the way, the other options like `rounded corners` and `align=center` will also be inherited by the matrix' cells' nodes but that's either required (`align=center` doesn't do much for the matrix) or not an issue (`rounded corners` won't be drawn).

---

Since your already using `matrix of nodes` you don't need the `\node`s in the matrix. And the `matrix` library also provides `matrix of math nodes`.

I've reorganizes some of your styles.

If you only need math matrices in that tree, I'd recommend using an actual math matrix (like the `matrix` environment from `amsmath`), then you can easily use also the `graphs` or (with LuaLaTeX) the `graphdrawing` library or the `forest` package.
I've added two examples that uses the same node style. (The nodes look a bit different because of the `inner sep`s that are used by TikZ nodes that won't be applied by `amsmath`, of course.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{
  forest, % for forest environment
  amsmath % for matrix environment (not TikZ \matrix!)
}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, matrix, graphs}
\newcommand*\mymatrix[1]{$\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level distance=2.5cm,
  sibling distance=3cm,
  matrix node/.style={
    matrix of math nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, matrix_nodes},
  matrix_nodes/.style={
    shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center,
     every outer matrix/.append style={
       minimum height=18mm,
       minimum width =25mm
     },
  },
  cells={text height=0.2cm, text width=0.5cm},
]
\node[matrix node] {
    3 \& 6 \\
}
    child {
        node[matrix node] {
            ct_1^5 \& ct_2^5 \& ct_3^5 \\
            cd_1^5 \& cd_2^5 \& cd_3^5 \\
               -8  \&        \&      8 \\
        }
    }
    child {
        node[matrix node] {
            3 \& 3 \\
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz[]
\graph[
  grow down sep,
  branch right sep,
  nodes={
    rounded corners,
    draw,
    minimum height=18mm,
    minimum width =25mm
  },
] {
  root/\mymatrix{3 & 6}
  -- {
    ch1/\mymatrix{
        ct_1^5 & ct_2^5 & ct_3^5 \\
        cd_1^5 & cd_2^5 & cd_3^5 \\
           -8  &        &      8
    },
    ch2/\mymatrix{3 & 3}
  }
};
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners,
    draw,
    minimum height=18mm,
    minimum width =25mm
  }
[\mymatrix{3 & 6}
  [\mymatrix{
     ct_1^5 & ct_2^5 & ct_3^5 \\
     cd_1^5 & cd_2^5 & cd_3^5 \\
        -8  &        &      8
  }]
  [\mymatrix{3 & 3}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here is a solution using `forest`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw, rounded corners, minimum width=7em, minimum height=10ex, s sep=5mm}
[$\begin{matrix}3 & 6\end{matrix}$
    [$\begin{matrix} ct_1^5 & ct_2^5 & ct_3^5 \\ cd_1^5 & cd_2^5 & cd_3^5 \\ -8 & & 8\end{matrix}$]
    [$\begin{matrix}3 & 3\end{matrix}$]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```